# remove table heading<th> from a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

Am using same table for displaying items in different pages.

```
var testhistbl = '<br><table width="680px" id="report"><tr style="display: table-row;"><th  valign="center">User</th><th  valign="center" >Test Name</th><th   valign="center">VM</th><th valign="center">Browsers</th><th  valign="center">Result</th><th>Error</th></tr>';
```

here is the code am using
in homepage i dont need to use Error header
Hoe can i remove this on home page

Answer (score 1):

```
$('th').closest('tr').remove();
```

Comment: Find every `<th>`, then step up to the enclosing `<tr>` and remove it. This will remove the entire header row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery( ":contains(text)" )](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to find the `th` with text *Error*.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8mpd3/)**

> The matching text can appear directly within the selected element, in
>   any of that element's descendants, or a combination thereof. As with
>   attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains()
>   can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks. The
>   text must have matching case to be selected, [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$('th:contains(Error)').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/). Try:

```
$('table#report th:contains(Error)').remove();
```

or

If `error` is always `last th` then use [`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/):

```
$('table#report th:last').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it depends upon the text (`Error`) you have, it is better to do with it.  Simply do with [**:contains**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [**remove()**](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```
$('th:contains("Error")').remove();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/689Uf/)